# Mysterious sum equal to $\frac{7(p^2-1)}{24}$ where $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider a prime number $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $n_p$ denotes the remainder of $n$ upon division by $p$. Let $A_p=\{ a \in [[0,p]] \mid {(a+1)^2}_p<{a^2}_p\}$.

I Conjecture

$$\sum_{n \in A_p } n=\dfrac{7(p^2-1)}{24}$$

The question has already been asked in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639883/mysterious-sum-equal-to-frac7p2-124-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4?noredirect=1#comment9793873_4639883). If it is a repetition, please vote to close this thread.

**Addition**  After have [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639883/mysterious-sum-equal-to-frac7p2-124-where-p-equiv-1-pmod4/4640608#4640608)  Numerically, I find this equality  :  for every odd integer p ≥ 3  $$\sum_{n \in A_p} n=\dfrac{7p^2 -12p+5}{24}+\dfrac{1}{p}\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}{n^2}_p$$  Perhaps, it is useful to demonstrate in a simple way the fact that [the sum differs from 7(p^2-1)/24 by the class number of Q(sqrt(-p))](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639930/even-more-mysterious-sum-equaling-to-frac7p2-124-h-p-where-p-equ).

Comment: What is $[[0,p]]$?

Comment: $[0.p]\cap \mathbb N$

Comment: . . . and as already noted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639930 when p is -1 mod 4 the sum differs from 7(p^2-1)/24 by the class number of Q(sqrt(-p)) !  This too is yet unproved.

Comment: To test that I understand correctly, for $p=5$ we are talking about $3+4$, because $0^2_5 < 1^2_5 < 2^2_5 = 3^2_5 > 4^2_5 > 5^2_5$, right?

Comment: Let $(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1\equiv\alpha\pmod{p}$ and $a^2\equiv \beta\pmod{p}$. Then $\beta-\alpha\equiv-2a-1\pmod{p}$. Also for $a\in A_p$ we have $\beta-\alpha\geq1$. But according to the size of $a$, I think we should get $\beta-\alpha=2p-2a-1$. Not sure though.

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with primes. Try for instance powers of primes 1 mod 4 (the pattern is immediate for powers 2,3,4 for instance), or products of primes 1 mod 4, where the same formula holds (and probably also with class numbers).

Comment: This has been [answered in your MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4640608/471884). Generally it's best practice to leave a reasonable amount of time (at least a week) between crossposts to avoid situations like this.

Comment: Thank you very much , I received a proof in the other thread that I had reported here

Comment: I have added a numerical result that I think is interesting

Comment: @Pascal I did some simple computations, this problem is so interesting feels like doing more, so I think we have $\sum_{a\in A_p}a^2=\frac{(p-1)(5p^2+7p-10)}{24}$. In general I think it is interesting to know if there is a degree $d$ polynomial $P_d$ such that $\frac{24}{p-1}\sum_{a\in A_p}a^d=P_d(p)$ for any prime $1$ modulo $4$ and if there are some patterns for the polynomials $P_d$.

Comment: @SB1729  Good question

Comment: In the same vein, see also in Franz Lemmermeyer's book "Reciprocity Laws", especially chapter 1 and exercise 1.32 (Gauss).